# Точность вычислений в языке python

Tags: python

Столкнулся с некой странностью с действительными числами в python.

Например, `print(0.3+0.3+0.3)` вместо вполне ожидаемых 0.9 выведет 0.8999999999999999.

Знаю про точность вычислений, про хранение в компьютере вещественных чисел, но почему, `print(0.3*3 == 0.9)` выдает false?

UPD Можно обойти это, сравнивая вот так `print('%.2f'%(0.3*3) == '%.2f'%(0.9))`
Но есть ли какой-нибудь другой способ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Это не связано с Питоном. [Числа с плавающей точкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9) так работают. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что 0.3 - это не ровно 0.3, а, как вы сами предположили, немного меньше. Что и дает требуемую погрешность при умножении.

Представьте, что по каким-то причинам компьютер сохраняет числа в формате 0.01 + 0.02k. В этом случае 0.3 будет преобразован в 0.299, а 0.9 - в 0.899. Теперь же, если умножить 0.3 на 3, будет получен результат 0.897, а не 0.899.

Вышеописанный пример не имеет **никакого** отношения к реальности, но, надеюсь, показывает, как при умножении минимальная погрешность становится достаточно большой, чтобы результирующее число было округлено в нужную сторону.

0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3 же будет равно 0.3 * 3, хотя гарантировать постоянное соблюдение этого равенства я не берусь.