# Погрешность при суммировании python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x

простой код:

```
    i = 0
while i < 5:
    i += 0.1
    print("i = ", i)
```

результат:

```
i =  0.1
i =  0.2
i =  0.30000000000000004
i =  0.4
i =  0.5
i =  0.6
i =  0.7
i =  0.7999999999999999
i =  0.8999999999999999
i =  0.9999999999999999
i =  1.0999999999999999
i =  1.2
i =  1.3
i =  1.4000000000000001
```

Откуда берется погрешность?

Comment: потому что так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488225/%d0%a2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-python

Comment: Числа с плавающей точкой не совсем точные, смотрите дубликат вопроса по ссылке